# How to alter an existing column to default to the current time on insert, in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, default, alter

I'm trying to change the existing column "time_sent" to default to the time during insertion. My SQL is:

```
ALTER TABLE `email_history` alter `time_sent` set DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I'm getting this error though:

```
 MySQL said: 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 1
```

I've read the documentation and other (similar, but not identical) examples, and no luck.

My version of MySQL is 5.0.67 I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be ..

```
ALTER TABLE 'table' MODIFY collumn_1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Is that backtick at the end meant to be there? If yes, should there be 2 of them?

Comment: That worked, thanks! The link you provided doesn't seem to use "MODIFY" though? Shall we remove the link?